# GPL VirtualBox in Ubuntu Server. Questions about setting up Ubuntu guest OS's

Tags: virtualization, ubuntu, virtualbox

I want to have one Ubuntu Server containing virtual machines who are also running Ubuntu Server. I want to use the GPL version of VirtualBox for this and I have some questions:

- Is it important that I run linux-virtual for a kernel adapted for running as virtual?
- I want the guest OS's to use a virtual network interface which gets its address from my DHCP-server just as a normal computer would. Is it hard to set that up? How do I do it?
- I do not want to run the GUI for VirtualBox, I want to use the command line as the server hasn't got X installed. Does this make it much harder for me?

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations on deciding to wander down the wonderful path of virtualization.

- You do not have to run linux-virtual kernel. VirtualBox compiles its own kernel module to handle virtualization. See [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#id2499965).
- See [Host-Only networking](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#network_hostonly) in the VirtualBox Manual. It is not very hard to set up but you do need to understand how networks and routing works.
- It doesn't make it too much harder. VirtualBox uses a program called VBoxHeadless to run a VM without a GUI and the command [VBoxManage](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#vboxmanage) to set configuration options.

Running VirtualBox without a GUI works very well - I have a server which runs 3 VMs and has for over a year with no bug hiccups - besides the downtime that I need to take in order to upgrade VirtualBox on the host machine.  I used a CentOS host machine with Ubuntu and Windows guests.

For a full tutorial on using VBoxHeadless with Ubuntu check out [HowToForge](http://www.howtoforge.com/vboxheadless-running-virtual-machines-with-virtualbox-3.0-on-a-headless-ubuntu-9.04-server).

Answer (score 1):

I think, Bridged mode would be better to use you networked dhcp.
In plus, you could add another Vm easily by this method.